# ToString("X") produces single digit hex numbers

Tags: c#, hex

We wrote a crude data scope.

(The freeware terminal programs we found were unable to keep up with Bluetooth speeds)

The results are okay, and we are writing them to a Comma separated file for use with a spreadsheet. It would be better to see the hex values line up in nice columns in the RichTextBox instead of the way it looks now (Screen cap appended).

This is the routine that adds the digits (e.g., numbers from `0` to `FF`) to the text in the RichTextBox.

```
  public void Write(byte[] b)
         {
             if (writting)
             {
                 for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
                 {
                     storage[sPlace++] = b[i];

                     pass += b[i].ToString("X") + " ";  //// <<<--- Here is the problem

                     if (sPlace % numericUpDown1.Value == 0)
                     {
                         pass += "\r\n";
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
```

I would like a way for the instruction `pass += b[i].ToString("X") + " ";` to produce a leading zero on values from `00h` to `0Fh`

Or, some other way to turn the value in byte `b` into two alphabetic characters from `00` to `FF`

[image]

Digits on left, `FF 40 0 5` Line up nice and neatly, because they are identical. As soon as we encounter any difference in data, the columns vanish and the data become extremely difficult to read with human observation.

Comment: You probably don't care any more, but this really should use a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) rather than repeatedly concatenate strings.

Comment: Does your UI control use a monospace font too? Looks like a 1 is much narrower than an A so even if you format the hex well it'll still be misaligned

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use a [composite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) format string:

```
pass += b[i].ToString("X2") + " ";
```

The documentation on MSDN, [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) has examples.

Comment: @User.1 `0.ToString("X2")` produces `00`. The `2` means how many characters to output (padding with `0`s).

Comment: I get this answer, but it doesn't solve the problem of using a font that isn't monospaced, such as Consolas or Courier New.

Comment: @Tim - The main issue was with single digit output. A monospace font would be the other part of the solution.

Comment: @Tim Oded's answer, plus this line, gives us the barebones data scope we want: `richTextBox1.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 14);` I *think* you can put it anywhere in `Form1_Load`