# What is the meaning of ToString("X2")?

Tags: c#, encryption, tostring

I'm studying MD5 encryption, and have found this code using Google:

```
public string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{

    // Primeiro passo, calcular o MD5 hash a partir da string
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    // Segundo passo, converter o array de bytes em uma string haxadecimal
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Why does it use `ToString("X2")`? How is it different from normal `ToString`?

Comment: I tried, I saw visual difference, but I don't know what it has did

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233290/tostringx-produces-single-digit-hex-numbers  same thing here

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx . Just type *tostring format* to google and navigate to the first result.

Comment: Check out the standard numeric string formats for .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank so much and sorry for my question

Comment: Don't be sorry! We're all here to learn.

Comment: @L.B FYI, as many "simple" questions on StackOverflow, this one is now the first result in Google for some searches. I think there's always value for this type of question for this very reason.

Comment: Yes, Google brings people here and it's faster than 'trying myself' :|

Answer (score 158, accepted):

It formats the string as two uppercase hexadecimal characters.

In more depth, the argument `"X2"` is a "format string" that tells the `ToString()` method how it should format the string. In this case, "X2" indicates the string should be formatted in Hexadecimal.

`byte.ToString()` without any arguments returns the number in its natural decimal representation, with no padding.

Microsoft documents the [standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) which generally work with all primitive numeric types' `ToString()` methods. This same pattern is used for other types as well: for example, [standard date/time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) can be used with `DateTime.ToString()`.

Comment: In case anyone has read Clean Code and is thinking ... "could we just get this named ToHexString() in the framework" ... and we can all stop writing our own extension functions? X2 doesn't just roll of the brain for some of us. Maybe the format string "2HX" but that's just trying to be cute.

Comment: format as MINIMUM of two uppercase hex characters. If there are more than two it will return all of them. so F would return as 0F but FFF would return as FFF.

Comment: Yep "X2" provides two values that can be controlled separately as needed. The 2 specifies the minimum number of characters to return, while the X specifies to output in Hex according to its case. So while X4 might produce 00FF, x4 would produce 00ff.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity. Two hex digits represent 256 bits which is the equivalent to 1 byte. So it's a naturally elegant pairing. In the case of a byte array, it works fantastically. Using a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder), one can output a shortened hexadecimal string representation of something like the output of a hashing function.

Answer (score 61):

It prints the `byte` in Hexadecimal format.

> No format string:           13
>
> 'X2' format string:         0D

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa311428(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 18):

ToString("X2") prints the input in Hexadecimal